# How to project a layer from WGS84 lat/long (automatic projection) to WGS 84 UTM Zone 23S in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-2.8

So I have a vector layer of polygons in WGS 84 lat/long (i.e. using the automatic projection for lat/long and WGS84 datum). I want to change that to WGS84 UTM 23S in QGIS. I tried doing like online tutorials show (right-click layer, "save as", and choose the CRS you want) but there has been zero distortions to the polygons, even for very big ones comprising tens of kilometers. In other words, it didn't work.
Can anybody help?
I'm using QGIS 2.8.2.

---

Somebody please help. It's suppose to be simple, but I can't get my head around this zero distortion problem. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

If you view the layer in QGIS with `On-the-fly-reprojection`enabled (which is default if the loaded layers have different CRS). you will not see any difference.

That is the deeper sense of reprojecting: The object stays on the same spot on Earth, but the coordinates change.

If you turn **off** `otf`, you will see the layers on different places after zooming to the extent.

Comment: I didnt try that. What I actually did was open a new project and set WGS84 UTM23S as the project CRS. Then I just added the vector layer which I had saved with UTM coordinates. The shape is the same.

Anyways, I did what you suggested. It turns out that the shape is still the same, but the new layer is millions of kilometers away.
I'm really confused on how to get this done. It is supposed to be trivial. Please help.

Comment: Can you add the extent of both layers, as reported by properties, metadata tab?

Comment: FOR THE ONE IN WGS84 LATLONG
Extents
In layer spatial reference system units
xMin,yMin -44.4157,-20.5506 : xMax,yMax -43.1225,-19.5514
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs


FOR THE ONE IN WGS84 UTM
Extents
In layer spatial reference system units
xMin,yMin 561209.09,7727205.66 : xMax,yMax 696978.82,7837082.42
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=utm +zone=23 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs

Comment: I think I figured part of the problem. The distance between the layers is expected. After all, with OTF projection unabled, QGIS is using utm coordinates as lat/long. That is why they are so distant.
However the problem remains that the shape is absolutely equal. If there is one thing to expect from lat/long to utm is distortion. Right?

Comment: No, **all** coordinates of vertex points get reprojected, but stay on the same spot on Earth. So you will see no effect with otf on. It's just the coordinates changing.

Comment: "So you will see no effect with otf on." Right, I know that. But if I turn otf off, or even open a new project in UTM WGS84, shouldn't the shape change?.

Comment: You are probably too close to the equator to see great changes.

Comment: Actually the area is far off from the equator. So QGIS simply fails to do basic reprojections?

Comment: AndreJ do you have any other advice or should I just move on?

Comment: I don't see why you insist on having distortions. Close to the poles you will get them, because degrees of latitude and longitude differ much, but not at 20°S. The decrease of Longitudes is not linear, but with the cos of Latitude.

Comment: That is kinda intuitive to me. I have used ArcGIS for years, making maps of the same area, and I would always get distortions when making CRS conversions from latlong to UTM. I'm new to QGIS but although the procedure changes the end result should be the same. That is why I'm confused.

Comment: From QGIS documentation page: "Notice how the shape of South Africa changes. All projections work by changing the apparent shapes of objects on Earth."

Comment: Just found the solution. Apparently opening a new project with UTM CRS and adding the UTM layer doesn't work. The shape is unchanged. But if I change the current project CRS and enable OTF reprojection there is the slight distortion I was hoping for. Don't know why but that'll do. Thank you for the help and patience AndreJ.

Answer (score 2):

You should also change the CRS of the project by clicking the grey planet on the bottom right:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using QGIS 2.4, but I think it's the same: click the menu PROCESSING, then TOOLBOX.

In the Toolbox, type REPROJECT LAYER. Click to open the algorithm. You can select the layer you want to change the coordinate system (INPUT LAYER), and it will result in a new layer (REPROJECTED LAYER), with the new coordinate system.

[image]

Comment: I tried that too. It is the same as "right-clicking and save as" with a new CRS.

Just found the solution. Apparently opening a new project with UTM CRS and adding the UTM layer won't do. The shape is unchanged. But if I change the current project CRS and enable OTF reprojection there is a slight distortion. Don't know why but that'll do. Thank you.

Comment: From the [docs](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_general_tools.html) it should do what you want, and I've used it many times and it works, but I don't know about the distortions.